# select and click option with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi guys i have one select and many options and many frag .. ineed chose one option and in body 2 frag goes display : none;  but i cant do it plz help me:

i know this code is wrong but icant find code for this work:

help me thanks

```
   `<select id="`myselect`">
<option class="`ukk`" value="1">uk</option>
<option class="usaa" value="2">usa</option>
<option class="euu" value="3">eu</option>
</select>

<div id="frag1">uk frag</div>
<div id="frag2">usa frag</div>
<div id="frag3">eu frag</div>

$('.ukk').click(function(){
  $('#frag2').hide();
})`
```

Comment: Why has your option with the class ukk backticks? I would guess without backticks your code would work in principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add onchange event on select
2. Compare class name and hide

```js
$("select").on("change", function(){
  if($(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("ukk")){
    $("#frag2").hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
<option class="ukk" value="1">uk</option>
<option class="usaa" value="2">usa</option>
<option class="euu" value="3">eu</option>
</select>

<div id="frag1">uk frag</div>
<div id="frag2">usa frag</div>
<div id="frag3">eu frag</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do on your select a on change event handler and then check which option is selected

so in your  Jquery script it's

```
$('#myselect').change(function(){
    switch($('#myselect :selected').attr('class')){
        case "ukk":
            //do what ever you want
            break;
        case ...
    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the event on change of `myselect`, then check class to do something as you wish like below.

```js
$('#myselect').on("change", function(){
   var className = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("class");
   $(".frag").show();
   console.log(".frag_" + className);
   $(".frag_" + className).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
<option class="ukk" value="1">uk</option>
<option class="usaa" value="2">usa</option>
<option class="euu" value="3">eu</option>
</select>

<div class="frag frag_ukk" >uk frag</div>
<div class="frag frag_usaa" >usa frag</div>
<div class="frag frag_euu" >eu frag</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @amirsalmani

Answer (score 0):

I think thats the logic your looking for?

```css
$('body').on('change', '#myselect', function () {
  $('#frag1, #frag2, #frag3').css('display', 'none');
  if ($(this).val()=='1') {
    $('#frag1').css('display', 'inherit');
  }
  else if($(this).val()=='2') {
    $('#frag2').css('display', 'inherit');
  }
  else if($(this).val()=='3') {
    $('#frag3').css('display', 'inherit');
  }
  else {
    $('#frag1, #frag2, #frag3').css('display', 'inherit');
  }
}

);
```

```html
<select id="myselect">
  <option>Choose one...</option>
  <option class="ukk" value="1">uk</option>
  <option class="usaa" value="2">usa</option>
  <option class="euu" value="3">eu</option>
</select>

<div id="frag1">uk frag</div>
<div id="frag2">usa frag</div>
<div id="frag3">eu frag</div>
```